# Is it clear to say "at multiple positions in a video"?

Tags: word-usage

[Is it common to pronounce two /tjuː/?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249888/115654) says

> The word "two" in a tutorial sounds like /tjuː/ **at multiple positions**.

By "at multiple positions" I mean that, the speaker pronounces that way [at 1:09](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=69), and pronounces that way again [at 2:23](https://youtu.be/nbnRm_3_QKU?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=143), and so on.

Is it clear it and grammatically correct to use "at multiple positions" to convey that idea?

Comment: My preference would be for **points** although **positions** is clear.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. How about "several parts"?

Comment: **parts** doesn't really work unless 1) the video is divided into a small number of distinct parts, and 2) it is somehow significant that the mis-pronounced word occurs in more than one distinct part.

Comment: "At multiple positions" sounds overly formal. I would just say **several times**.

Answer (score 1):

It is unambiguous what the sentence means, so in that sense it's clear.

There are several words you could use to express this, though I don't think any is obviously dominant.  "Positions" or "points" are probably the cleanest with this particular formation.

Alternatively, you could also say "[At several **places**/Several **times**] in the video/tutorial, the word 'two' sounds like /tjuː/", which is a little more colloquial.

Comment: Thank you. How about "several parts"?

Answer (score 0):

A native speaker would understand it, but it sounds odd because it is unusual to use "position" to refer to a time.

The word **timestamp** would cover this meaning (a moment in time of a video) perfectly, but some people might consider this to be computer jargon.

If you want to use a less technical term, I think "multiple **moments** in the video" would be a good choice.