# places in the video vs. places of the video

Tags: prepositions

the following sentence is adapted from https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/249939/115654

> At several places **in the video**, the word 'two' sounds like /tjuː/

Could I use "of" there? Because those places are part of the video.

> At several places **of the video**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, "places of" sounds wrong, but "places in" sounds right. So does "points in". If you wanted to use "of" then "parts of" or "sections of" are right.